# Make the CodeMirror merge view addon display a count of differences found

Tags: javascript, textarea, diff, codemirror

While using CodeMirror’s [`merge` addon](http://codemirror.net/demo/merge.html), I am interested in knowing the *count of differences* found in the L.H.S. and the R.H.S. `textarea`s, respectively.

Is there a way of displaying the count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement it yourself, by using the [diff-match-patch](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch) library that the `merge` addon depends on. Write an `updateDiffCount` function that uses the following algorithm:

1. Get the two text versions you are comparing as strings.
2. Call [`diff_main`](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch/wiki/API#diff_maintext1-text2--diffs) on the strings and [`diff_cleanupSemantic`](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch/wiki/API#diff_cleanupsemanticdiffs--null) on the result, as in [this code example](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch/wiki/Language:-JavaScript).
3. Loop through the results and count the result arrays whose first element is not `0`.
4. Set the text contents of some element on your page to that count.

Run this `updateDiffCount` function whenever the text in the `textarea` is edited, after a delay.

Answer (score 1):

I added some code to Rory's solution to make it easier to implement:

```
var text1 = document.getElementById('text1').value;
var text2 = document.getElementById('text2').value;

var d = dmp.diff_main(text1, text2);

// you can optionally add some cleanup
// dmp.diff_cleanupSemantic(d); or dmp.diff_cleanupEfficiency(d);

alert('Difference count: ' + d.filter(l => l[0] === -1).length);
```